# spectral_norm on GCNConv module

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I want to call torch.nn.utils spectral_norm function on a GCNConv layer

```
gc1 = GCNConv(18, 16)
spectral_norm(gc1)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'weight'
```

meaning gc1._parameters doesn't have weight (only bias):

```
gc1._parameters
OrderedDict([('bias', Parameter containing:
              tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                     requires_grad=True))])
```

However, gc1.parameters() stores two objects and one of them is a 16 by 18 matrix (weight matrix).

```
for p in gc1.parameters():
  print('P: ', p.shape)
P:  torch.Size([16])
P:  torch.Size([16, 18])
```

How can I make spectral_norm function work on a GCNConv module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/conv/gcn_conv.html#GCNConv), the weight parameter is wrapped within a linear module contained in GCNConv objects as `lin`.

I imagine that this should then work:

```
gc1 = GCNConv(18, 16)
spectral_norm(gc1.lin)
```

Comment: Thanks! gc1 = GCNConv(18, 16)
gc2 = spectral_norm(gc1.lin); gc1(data.x, data.edge_index) works fine, but gc2(data.x, data.edge_index) returns an error: TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. is there a way to fix that as well?